# Delete record from many to many entity in Zend using Doctrine 2

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery, zend-framework2

I am working on Zend Doctrine. I have a many-to-many entity `groups_contacts` which has fields `group_id` and `contact_id` linked to relevant tables `group` and `contact` and created in `group` entity.

I am creating `groups_contacts` in `group` entity which is a many-to-many relationship.

Following is the code of delete action:

```
public function deleteGroupMemberAction() {
    $auth_service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default');
    $objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
    $user = $auth_service->getIdentity();
    //die($_POST['g_id'] . ' removed');

    $query_deleteMember = $em->createQuery('delete from groups_contacts gc where gc.contact_id = 7 and gc.group_id = 1');

    $numDeleted = $query_deleteMember->execute();
    die($query_deleteMember. ' removed');

    $objectManager->flush();
    die($title . ' removed');
}
```

This function called on ajax call which is working perfectly.

I don't know why the delete query is not working, I tried other ways but get the same result. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the mapping to your entity

```
delete from MyMapping:groups_contacts gc where gc.contact_id = 7 and gc.group_id = 1
```

Or put your namespace:

```
delete from Your\Name\Space\groups_contacts gc where gc.contact_id = 7 and gc.group_id = 1
```

But that's not enough because you can not access these `contact_id` and `group_id` columns directly. So you would have to write:

```
delete from MyMapping:groups_contacts gc JOIN gc.contact c JOIN gc.group g where c.id = 7 and g.id = 1
```

Wow two joins .. this should be simpler in native SQL. Does it even execute those JOINS? Perhaps Doctrine will optimize it and not use the JOIN in the final query.

The use case is a bit weird though. Suppose you have a website which lists groups and their contacts. The relation is represented by groups_contacts (on a site note you should only make this a seperate entity when the relation needs to hold data itself). Then when the user wants to remove a relationship (disconnect a contact from a group) the relationship (represented by groups_contacts) can just be identified with it's own id. Then your query would become:

```
DELETE FROM MyMapping:groups_contacts gc WHERE gc.id = <user clicked relation>
```

Comment: Thank you so much flip, and sorry i couldn't join since i posted it. I was in a mess.!

I done it in another way using the doctrine property "removeElement" and then persist. 
And i am sure now the way you explained will work anyway. It looks perfect to me.

Comment: upvote always is nice :) Maybe you can post your own answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

### controller

$group = $em->find("Application\Entity\Group", $group_id);

```
        if ($group->getCreatedBy()->getId() == $user->getId()) {
            $contact = $em->find("Application\Entity\UserProfile", $contact_id);
            if (isset($contact)) {
                $group->getContacts()->removeElement($contact);
                $objectManager->persist($group);
                $objectManager->flush();
```

### }

### Group Entity

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserProfile")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="groups_contacts",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="contact_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
```

### private $contacts;

It's better to handle many-to-many relationship this way, in which you have to get the group and the contact ids you want to remove from associative entity by usingthe removeElement and then persist with the relevant id of group